# Render PNG file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, png, image-rendering

I have a Rails app where I am trying to display a PNG file but I am getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8. Please either specify UTF-8 as the encoding for your template in your text editor, or mark the template with its encoding by inserting the following as the first line of the template:

# encoding: <name of correct encoding>.

The source of your template was:

�PNG

IHDR#ͱ�)    pHYs�]s� IDATx���g@SW�E��7�ZuV묣�Z�:j�mպm�Z��U[W�:�պZ�*�j���@�3� I���p��}
��?�
���b�X�/���Z�I�N111,ӧO��x�T�?x۶mU����vtt
```

I've added:

```
Mime::Type.register "image/png", :png
```

to the config/initializers/mime_types.rb

I'm referencing and rendering the png file in its controller with:

```
render :inline => @object.body.string, :content_type => @object.content_type || "img/png", :layout => false
```

EDIT :

This is the method in the controller

```
 def read_data
  resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: @new_client)
  if @files.size == 0 && @links.size == 0 && resource.bucket(@bucket.name).objects.first != nil && !request.original_url.end_with?('/')
  if request.original_url.split('/')[-1] != @bucket.name && resource.bucket(@bucket.name).object(@prefix).exists?
     @object = @new_client.get_object(bucket: @bucket.name, key: @prefix)
     if @prefix.present? && @object.last_modified && (@object.content_type.match(/text/) || @object.content_type.match("application/json") || @prefix.end_with?('.json') || @prefix.end_with?('.html') || @prefix.end_with?('.txt') || @prefix.end_with?('.xml') || (@object.content_length > 0 && @object.content_type == ""))
      render :inline => @object.body.string, :content_type => @object.content_type || "text/plain", :layout => false
     elsif @prefix.end_with?('.png')
         send_data(@object.body, 
                   :type         => @object.content_type || "image/png",
                   :disposition  => 'inline')
     else
      redirect_to resource.bucket(@bucket.name).object(@prefix).presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 8) #presigned url expires after 8 ms
    end
  end
end
```

end

Comment: You need to learn how HTML works. Binary objects, like images are NOT embedded inside the HTML, they're referenced using "uniform resource locator" ([URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)s), which the browser then rerequests from the server referenced in the host section of the URL. At no time does the HTML contain binary data, it only contains text. If you want the browser to download something you can send the data as a separate stream, but that's a different process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`send_data`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) method to send binary files:

```
send_data(
  @object.body.string, 
  type: @object.content_type || 'image/png', 
  disposition: 'inline'
)
```

Comment: I tried adding it, but it gave me the same error when opening

Comment: Did you remove the `render` line and added `send_data` instead? Are you sure you need `@object.body.string` and not just `@object.body`?

Comment: Yeah, I replaced the render line with the send_data method and I've tried both `@object.body.string` and `@object.body`

Comment: And you get the exact same error? Please post you view and controller code.

Comment: On Safari you should use for mime-type: 'image/png' (not img), otherwise it downloads the file. Opposed to the inline disposition. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your controller action:

```
respond_with @resource do |format|
    # format.html { send_data @resource.body } # => Download the image file.
    format.html { send_data @resource.body,
                  type: @resource.content_type || 'image/png',
                  disposition: 'inline' } # => Show in browser page.
end
```